# Can I use TLS with the domain name automatically assigned by an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

When setting up an ELB, a subdomain is automatically provisioned (something like `some-junk-here.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`). For my use-case this ugly domain is fine, and it works for raw HTTP and TCP connections, but we'd like to enable TLS. Is there a way to use TLS without setting up a custom domain? I think this would work by having the ELB use an Amazon-provided wildcard cert to unwrap TLS connections, and proxy the bare connection to my EC2 instance (I believe this is what  services like Heroku, ngrok etc do)

Just connecting over HTTPS (or a TLS-wrapped TCP connection) doesn't seem to work by default, and I haven't found any documentation about this (everything I've seen to do with TLS involves adding my own domain and cert)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work.  A TLS certificate provides two things: keys for setting up encryption and an assurance that the server is not an impostor and is authorized to serve requests for the given domain.  Obtaining such a cert requires you to own or control the domain, but `amazonaws.com` isn't yours.  This is why all the examples involve a custom domain.  The hostname of an AWS load balancer is there to give you a DNS target that isn't an IP address, something to point your domain to in DNS, because the IP addressss of load balancers will change over time due ro scaling, failures, or upgrades.

You can create your own self-signed certificates or even your own private certificate authority using openssl (or easyrsa, a wrapper for openssl) and if your clients are such that you can update their trust stores, but the simplest solution is just get a domain, or create a subdomain from one you already have.  The domain doesn't technically even have to be hosted in Route 53.  Then get the cert from Amazon Certificate Manager, which is free.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Amazon isn't going to give me their certs, but could they not unwrap a TLS connection using that cert for me? My understanding is that a number of other services that provide their users TLS on dynamic subdomains (eg https://yourapp.herokuapp.com) do this by having a wildcard cert that they use to unwrap the incoming connection, and then pass the unencrypted traffic on to your app. Couldn't AWS do the same thing? Or are you just saying that they _could_ but choose not to?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  They technically *could* furnish a wildcard cert -- they do this on `*.s3.amazonaws.com` and `*.cloudfront.net` -- but they don't do this for ELBs.  And since they are the only ones who could, it isn't otherwise possible.  Let's Encrypt, for example, has specific rules that prevent them from generating certs for anything in the amazonaws.com domain, even though http nonce validation would technically work fine.